# updating the value of items in a list in netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have 4 producers who have different attributes such as  their new product's price, size, customer rates. I defined 4 lists representing them.

`set att-price ((list p1-pr p2-pr p3-pr p4-pr))`   ;prices of all the products of 4 producers

```
set att-size ((list p1-sz p2-sz p3-sz p4-sz))



set att-rates ((list p1-rt p2-rt p3-rt p4-rt))
```

As the time passes, the prices get updates, so I defined this to make this happen :

`set (item 0 att-price) (item 0 att-price) * 0.20`    ; changes in the price of product of producer one

```
set (item 1 att-price) (item 1 att-price) * 0.08

set (item 3 att-price) (item 3 att-price) * 0.43
```

But it has an error saying that "This isn't what you can "set" on"!

How can I update those items then?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`replace-item`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#replace-item) for this. For instance:

```
set att-price replace-item 0 att-price (0.2 * item 0 att-price)
```

That is, rather than setting the items of the list, we're making a new list with the item replaced, and then setting our list variable to that item.

If you want to replace all items at once, you can use [`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map). For instance, it looks like you might have a list of price ratios by which your prices change:

```
let ratios [ 0.2 1.0 0.08 0.43 ]
set att-price (map [ [ price ratio ] -> price * ratio ] att-price ratios)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `set att-price replace-item 0 (0.2 * item 0 att-price) att-price` to replace `set (item 0 att-price) (item 0 att-price) * 0.20` but an error is found saying that  "replace-item" expected this input to be a string or list, but got a number instead.

Comment: @user710 The new value comes last:
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#replace-item

Comment: Thanks so much Alan. Yes by doing `set att-price replace-item 0  att-price (0.2 * item 0 att-price)`, it works well :)